# Is it possible for 3 stimulus checks paid for one dependent?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stimulus

Mother remarried files Married Separate in 2019, receives $1400 based on 2019 tax return for dependent. Father receives $1400 based on 2020 tax return for dependent. Stepfather files Married Separate and claims dependent stepchild for 2021 tax return and recovers $1400. The same dependent child in all 3 cases. Would this be correct?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that, yes, that is possible, if those people were really eligible to claim that dependent in those tax years, and the mother didn't file 2020 tax returns yet by the early 2021 date when the EIP3 payment amount was determined.